# a single regex for all location paths regardless of the name in nginx?

Tags: regex, url, mod-rewrite, nginx

We have an angular app hosted on nginx which uses random url paths. Am trying to write a regex to match them all to redirect them to a common index.html file.
Which means all traffic to

```
domain.com/abc
domain.com/xyz
```

should all go to the index.html file.
Here's what i have been trying:

```
location ~* ^/[a-z](.+)$ {
rewrite ^ /index.html last;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

This doesnt work. Kindly help.

Comment: The regular expression you provide expects to match the *entire* string. If `nginx` gives you `domain.com/abc` that expression will not match. Also, it might be the case that `/` needs to be escaped. Maybe something like this would work? `^\/[a-z](.+)$`.

Comment: does this match special characters like "-"? Also what if the url is like this: domain.com/abc/abc1

Comment: The character set `[a-z]`, should mean any lower case letter which is between `a` and `z`, so essentially the entire English lower case alphabet. According to your expression, the first letter after the `/` needs to be a lower case English letter. Other than that, the `(.+)$` should keep on matching any character till the end of the string.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt. This is as per the log file: rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.html"

Comment: I have tried to answer your question below. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means an answer, but it might be too long for a comment.

What I suppose is happening is that the rewrite rule is firing (I do not know if this is with your rule or with the changes I suggested). What could be happening would be that the request is redirected to `/index.html`, as expected, however, `/index.html` satisfies the regular expression, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/gF5uM7/1). This will cause an infinite loop, which is what I suppose is what `internal redirection cycle` means.

To fix this problem, you could try something like this: `\/(?!index\.html).+` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/gP5vA8/2)). This will ensure that `index.html` is not part of the string your are matching. This shoud break the cycle.